# SQL- return one record for two different values in the table

Tags: sql, database

Select country name and number of customers in it, *provided that UK and GB should be considered as same country.*
Customers (country, custID,)

```
+----------+-------------+
| custID   | country     |
+----------+-------------+
| 101      |         US  |
| 102      |         UK  |
| 103      |         GB  |
| 104      |         UAE |
| 105      |         UK  |
| 106      |         GB  |
+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: which database ? and what is the sql ?

Comment: Structured Query language, any database i just want a general query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to map the UK to Great Britain (or vice-versa).  Then just use a simple aggregation query to get the result you want.  Note that I map the country names in a separate subquery because ANSI SQL does not support grouping by a derived column.

```
SELECT
    country, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN country = 'GB' THEN 'UK' ELSE country END AS country
    FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: what does that 't' mean after ')' ?

Comment: @Hasan The `t` after the subquery is just an _alias_ for that derived table.  Some databases (e.g. Oracle) require that every derived table have an alias.  Whether you would need it would depend on the database you are using, but it is good practice to include it as a matter of habit.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question, you can try the following query

```
Select country, count(*) from Customers 
group by country;
```